# Set the recipient of a PagerDuty alerts programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-config, pagerduty

I am looking for ideas on how to set the recipient of PagerDuty alerts.

To give some context, I have an aws config rule that publishes a new event into an SNS topic, via EventBridge, each time the config rule is non-compliant then I have PagerDuty subscribed to the sns topic; PagerDuty successfully receives the alerts and forward them to the alert recipients, no issue is here.

My question is this: is it possible to set the recipient of the PagerDuty Alert based on the event that triggers the alert?

I am thinking about using lambda to query CloudTrail to extract the email address of the user initiating the event that causes the aws config to become non-compliant, but not sure how to set that email address as the recipient of the PagerDuty notification.

Is this even possible? or is there a better way to approach it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some options for thought:

Depending on the size of your instance you could build a specific service for each of the possible recipients. Either using the lambda you mentioned to control which service the alert is routed to. Or, alternatively, using a PagerDuty global Ruleset (or event orchestration) to route the alert based on its contents.

This doesn't need a much setup initially but the tradeoff is that it quickly becomes unwieldly at scale.

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/event-orchestration#global-orchestrations

---

I've also seen solutions that assign an escalation policy without a specific target to a service such as user account with no contact info. When an alert and incident are opened a webhook is sent to, for example, RunDeck and that tool takes action in PagerDuty. The correct recipient is assigned to the incident and requested to acknowledge.

The tradeoffs here are losing visual sight of who is on-call for a service and the lift to stand up RunDeck, a lambda, or some other listener to process the webhook event.

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/event-orchestration#webhooks
https://www.pagerduty.com/integrations/rundeck-runbook-automation/